Where can I find a discussion of the rod and hole thought experiment purporting to convey the "reality" of the Lorentz contraction?
I remember having heard a teacher of mine talking about the imaginary experiment of making a rod pass through a hole shorter than the rod thanks to the Lorentz contraction. The rod is parallel to the hole but its velocity is at an angle so that the rod can approach and reach the hole thanks to the component of its velocity normal to the hole, while being Lorentz contracted thanks to the component of its velocity parallel to the rod itself. Could someone suggest me some papers and/or books that discuss this experiment?

@PM2Ring See my new take on the paradox in an answer to the related question.

If you have only one time and one space dimension, such "angles" are not possible!

@m4r35n357 who said I have only one time and one space dimensions? The situation I describe is in 2+1 dimension.

Well fine then, but that situation is not commonly discussed or taught, so you might have mentioned it ;)

@m4r35n357 Maybe we're right.

Don't know.  I thought you were asking a question, not making a statement . . .

@m4r35n357 I was not making a statement. I was asking for references. (Meanwhile I could manage to find them by myself.)

This cannot work. In the rest frame of the rod, the hole will be contracted. It will just get worse.
